# Rails production env "uninitialized constant (NameError)" error in unicorn startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

My rails app fails to start when in production (using unicorn) but works perfectly fine in development.

The exact error given is:

```
ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Grocer (NameError)
```

The error is generated on a custom initializer file I have created to initialise a Grocer connection.

The problem isn't in the gem file. A '*bundle show grocer*' on the server shows Grocer is installed.

'RAILS_ENV=production rails console' on the server loads correctly and Grocer is available there.

My guess is that Unicorn is missing something... Is there any reason why when the rails app is started through unicorn it can't see the Grocer gem installed? Where should I look next to help debug this further?

Comment: What deploy environemnt are you using? Is unicorn running in production for sure?

Comment: Yes unicorn was running fine. It was running fine until I started implementing the grocer stuff. I deploy using capistrano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might sound like a silly suggestion ... Have you tried restarting unicorn?

Comment: That was it! I was sure my capistrano deploy script was restarting unicorn. I'll have to add that now. Thanks!

Comment: Hey it's not silly suggestion, after read your answer i restart my apache server and error resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
bundle install --deployment
```

should do the trick

Comment: That just re-installed all the gems ... no change to the error though.